# IntelliSense not showing MessageBoxResult

Tags: messagebox

I am working with a Windows Forms application in C# and Visual Studio 2005.

I am showing a message box within an button click event,

```
string messageBoxText = "Click OK to save your changes\n";
string caption = "Confirm Changes";
MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
//Display the MessageBox
MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button);

MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, button);
```

The  following error pops up on compilation:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'MessageBoxResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also, IntelliSense does not show any such thing as MessageBoxResult. I have seen this statement on MSDN. How to capture the response of the message (OK/Cancel) without using MessageBoxResult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MessageBoxResult Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult(VS.85).aspx) is only available on .NET 3.0+.  You're using 2.0.

Use `DialogResult` as Walt suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could try placing

```
using System.Windows;
```

at the top of your source.

Or try DialogResult instead.  That's in the System.Windows.Forms namespace, and is what Show() returns in my C# source files...

Comment: using System.Windows did not work either. I'll have to use DialogResult I think.

Answer (score 0):

First Add Reference PresentationFramework (best from NuGet) and make using System.Windows;. Then You must use System.Windows from PresentationFramework for MessageBoxResult.
Second make using Microsoft.Win32; and pick it up for SaveFileDialog.

Comment: From Review: Would you please add a code sample with these fixes to your answer?