# MessageBoxResult vs. DialogResult

Tags: c#, .net

Two questions here, hope that is OK.

First, and mainly, I am trying to prompt the user when they exit my application whether or not they really want to exit. My code is as follows:

```
private void exitToolStrip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult mBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit the program?", "Exit Program", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    switch (mBoxResult)
    {
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            this.Close();
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            break;
    }
}
```

According to `MSDN`, I should be using `MessageBoxResult mBoxResult`  rather than `DialogResult mBoxResult`.

I am using `.NET Framework 3.5`. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330378/intellisense-not-showing-messageboxresult) that `pre-3.0` should use `DialogResult`, but if I’m using `3.5`, shouldn't `MessageBoxResult` work?

When I try to call it, I get

> The type or namespace name `MessageBoxResult` could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

However, it works fine when I use DialogResult. Why is this?

My second question is regarding this piece of code:

```
case DialogResult.No:
break;
```

If somebody hits the `Cancel` button on the dialog, would it be proper to put anything in there besides the break? Or will everything function fine without it?

Comment: Just use DialogResult and make sure that you set the result type of each button so that it's properly captured / returned.. very simple thing to check

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DialogResult is for WinForms. MessageBoxResult is for SilverLight.

Just the `break` statement is fine for the `No` case. But using a switch statement is overkill here. `if (response == yes) Close();` would suffice.

Note however that this isn't an ideal way to do what you want. What if the user clicks the close button on the window border, or presses ALT+F4? Instead, you should handle the FormClosing event:

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit the program?", "Exit Program", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

By setting `e.Cancel` to `true`, you cancel the closure of the form. By doing nothing, you allow the form to close.

Answer (score 8):

- Use [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) if your application is a WinForms application
- Use [MessageBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx) if your application is a WPF/Silverlight application

As you can see, namespaces are different: `System.Windows.Forms` (Winforms) vs `System.Windows` (WPF).